# Getting sum of two different tables columns to single column with group_by

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

First query for InvoiceOne table to group_by category and get sum of totalExGst:

```
sortCategory = db.session.query(
            InvoiceOne.category, db.func.sum(
                InvoiceOne.totalExGst).label('Total')
        ).filter(and_(InvoiceOne.storeNumber == '98376', InvoiceOne.weekEndDate == '2020-03-22')).group_by(InvoiceOne.category)
```

Second query does same thing with BankData table:

```
sortCategory = db.session.query(
            BankData.category, db.func.sum(
                BankData.debit).label('Total_BankData')
        ).filter(and_(BankData.storeNumber == '98376', BankData.weekEndDate == '2020-03-22')).group_by(BankData.category)
```

**I would like to join this query together so instead of getting** `Total` **and** `Total_BankData`

**I can get only one column for total.**

Comment: can't really tell what you're trying to add up here; can you post example outputs of what they each give you Now and a desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you go with subqueries :

```
sortCategory1 = db.session.query(
    InvoiceOne.category,
    db.func.sum(InvoiceOne.totalExGst).label('Total')
).filter(
    and_(
        InvoiceOne.storeNumber == '98376',
        InvoiceOne.weekEndDate == '2020-03-22')
).group_by(InvoiceOne.category).subquery()

sortCategory2 = db.session.query(
    BankData.category, 
    db.func.sum(BankData.debit).label('Total_BankData')
).filter(
    and_(
        BankData.storeNumber == '98376', 
        BankData.weekEndDate == '2020-03-22')
).group_by(BankData.category).subquery()


sortCategoryTotal = db.session.query(
    sortCategory1.c.category,
    sortCategory1.c.Total + sortCategory2.c.Total_BankData
).join(sortCategory2, sortCategory1.c.category == sortCategory2.c.category)
```

Comment: Hello Thibaut, thanks for above solution, it is working, however, I need all categories from both table if they are not similar, as because of ```sortCategory1.c.category == sortCategory2.c.category```, getting only what similar category in both table. Any solution for that. Also, I am new to sqlAlchemy and would appreciate if get explanation of above code plz